# ModelStateDictionary alternative

Tags: c#, validation, modelstate

I'm trying to build an alternative of ModelState as when I return this from api like `return BadRequest(ModelState)` it doesn't have much information other than somethings gone wrong with the request. So I have decided to build an alternative which will eventually look like this:

```
{
   "code": 1000,
   "message": "Invalid request",
   "fields": [
     {
        "name": "Password",
        "message": "Password does not meet complexity requirements."
     }
    ]
}
```

In order to accomplish this, I have the following models in my api project:

ErrorResponse.cs:

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, Field> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Field.cs:

```
public class Field
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to using `FluentResults` I can determine the error from the service layer within my controller like so:

```
if (result.HasError<PasswordError>()) 
{

}
```

However I've realised that I now need to return the `ErrorResponse` but each `Field` has a name and the only way to know the name of the field is through the controller using:

```
nameof(RegisterRequest.Password)
```

Is there a way to do this in a clean generic way without using magic strings?

Comment: Structure of `ErrorResponse` conflicting with the expected output, `Fields` in json expected to be an array. Because `Field` type already has `name` you can change type of `ErrorResponse.Fields` to `public Field[] Fields { get; set; }`

Comment: @Fabio I understand, but this isn't the problem I am having. The problem I am having is not understand how to create a generic method which will create the error response

Comment: I assumed that `Result` object returned by the service already has required information (name and the message of the failed field). If not, I would say that then it should be service responsibility to provide required information, isn't so?

Comment: @Fabio The service returns the required information like code and message. It returns the error as a type like `PasswordError` so the controller will know what property within the request the error corresponds to. I don't think it should be the service responsibility as the service shouldn't care what controller has called the service. Instead the controller should map the service errors back as the controller knows the properties to deal with

Comment: In that case I would suggest to introduce a method `.ToErrorField()` in `PasswordError` class which will return instance of the `Field` type where you can "hardcode" field name, because obviously `PasswordError` will have "password" field. If you want to keep `Field` class away from domain project where errors are defined, then create extension methods for all error classes you want to expose to the api.